# Pandas conditional on index column

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame, and set index to be the DateTime column:

```
data['DateTime'] = pandas.to_datetime (data['DateTime'])
data = data.set_index('DateTime')
```

which I need to interpolate the data. However, this indexing later prevents me from doing

```
data = data[pandas.to_datetime (data['DateTime']) <= cutoff]
```

where `cutoff` is some datetime. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you need `.index` for compare `DatetimeIndex`:

```
data['DateTime'] = pandas.to_datetime (data['DateTime'])
data = data.set_index('DateTime')
data = data[data.index <= cutoff]
```

Also is sorted `DatetimeIndex` use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
data1 = data1.loc[:cutoff]
```

Sample:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10)
data = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10)}, index=rng)  
print (data)
            a
2017-04-03  0
2017-04-04  1
2017-04-05  2
2017-04-06  3
2017-04-07  4
2017-04-08  5
2017-04-09  6
2017-04-10  7
2017-04-11  8
2017-04-12  9

cutoff = '2017-04-08'
data1 = data[data.index <= cutoff]
print (data1)
            a
2017-04-03  0
2017-04-04  1
2017-04-05  2
2017-04-06  3
2017-04-07  4
2017-04-08  5

data1 = data1.loc[:cutoff]
print (data1)
            a
2017-04-03  0
2017-04-04  1
2017-04-05  2
2017-04-06  3
2017-04-07  4
2017-04-08  5
```

---

Thanks [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43499216/pandas-conditional-on-index-column/43499250?noredirect=1#comment74053516_43499250):

```
data1 = data1[:cutoff]
print (data1)
            a
2017-04-03  0
2017-04-04  1
2017-04-05  2
2017-04-06  3
2017-04-07  4
2017-04-08  5
```

Comment: Amazing. It would have taken me days and I still wouldn't have tried this. I will accept the answer in 10 mins.

Comment: Thanks, @piRSquared. Is there a performance difference between both methods?

Comment: @John no.  they should be about the same.