# pandas dataframe - add new row if new index, if existing then supplement the index with column data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have an array with 170 dataframes, each including:

```
      gender - year
name   M/F    count
```

so example:

```
          Gender   2015
William     M      12321
George      M      19000
....       ...      ....
```

Each dataframe in the array is for a different year. What i want to do is combine all dataframes to a single dataframe. With different years some names appear and others disappear, so not all dataframes have the same structure (different row count).

tldr what i want (source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html):

[image]

But using this method i get the error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (274, 96313), indices imply (274, 96174)
```

Which is because my dataframes (unlike the example) have different row counts (I think).

Here is my full code:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

import pandas as pd
zip_file = ZipFile('names.zip')


df = pd.DataFrame()
dfs = []
with zip_file as f:
    for name in f.namelist():

            df1 = pd.read_csv(zip_file.open(name), sep=',',names=['Gender',name])  #Name = year
            df.append(df1)
            print(newDf)
            dfs.append(df1)

result = pd.concat(dfs,axis=1)
print(result.head())
```

Ive tried both append,merge and concat but none of them seem to do what I'm searching for. the solutions I've found to this error aren't directly applicable to my case as I'm dealing with a long array of dataframes, and I haven't been able to get them to work with my code.

Comment: It seems it is data dependent problem, so not easy answer. Data are confidental? Also zip is huge?

Comment: @jezrael The dataset is not so big and also is not confidential. I have uploaded the file here:  http://fileshare.link/61af15d1f30094d8/names.zip if you want to have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem some values in index are duplicated, because some names should be `male` and also `female` like `Abbie`.

So solution is very easy - add only one value to `names` in `read_csv` and first with second column are converted to `unique MultiIndex`.

Also was changed columns names with splicing - removed first 3 and last 4 characters.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
zip_file = ZipFile('names1.zip')

dfs = []
with zip_file as f:
    for name in f.namelist():
        df1 = pd.read_csv(zip_file.open(name), sep=',',names=[name[3:-4]])
        dfs.append(df1)

result = pd.concat(dfs,axis=1)
```

---

```
print(result.head(10))


           1884  1885  1886   1887   1888   1889   1890   1891   1892   1893  \
Aaron   M  97.0  88.0  86.0   78.0   90.0   85.0   96.0   69.0   95.0   81.0   
Ab      M   NaN   6.0   NaN    5.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
Abb     M   5.0   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    6.0    5.0    NaN    NaN   
Abbie   F  98.0  88.0  84.0  104.0  137.0  107.0  140.0  124.0  119.0  115.0   
        M   NaN   NaN   NaN    5.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    5.0    NaN    NaN   
Abbott  M   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    6.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
Abby    F   6.0   5.0   7.0    5.0    9.0    8.0    6.0   12.0    6.0   10.0   
Abe     M  45.0  47.0  50.0   37.0   46.0   39.0   49.0   40.0   53.0   43.0   
Abel    M  14.0   6.0  16.0   11.0    8.0    9.0   14.0   10.0    8.0   13.0   
Abelina F   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   

           ...     1904  1905  1906   1907   1908   1909   1910   1911   1912  \
Aaron   M  ...    117.0  96.0  96.0  130.0  114.0  142.0  145.0  187.0  303.0   
Ab      M  ...      NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
Abb     M  ...      NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
Abbie   F  ...     80.0  73.0  72.0   79.0   84.0   57.0   79.0   77.0   90.0   
        M  ...      NaN   5.0   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    8.0    NaN    NaN   
Abbott  M  ...      NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN    5.0    NaN    8.0    8.0   
Abby    F  ...      NaN   NaN   6.0    5.0    NaN    8.0    6.0   13.0    8.0   
Abe     M  ...     52.0  65.0  50.0   65.0   57.0   67.0   74.0   94.0  172.0   
Abel    M  ...     10.0   6.0  11.0   10.0   15.0   16.0   11.0   30.0   40.0   
Abelina F  ...      NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   

            1913  
Aaron   M  417.0  
Ab      M    NaN  
Abb     M    5.0  
Abbie   F  121.0  
        M    7.0  
Abbott  M    5.0  
Abby    F   11.0  
Abe     M  202.0  
Abel    M   48.0  
Abelina F    NaN  

[10 rows x 30 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks, this did indeed fix it. I was focusing on the wrong things it seems.

Comment: Hmmm, I think this was very complicated data related problem. So without data really hard slove it. thanks and good luck!

Comment: Hey, I wasn't able to comment on that specific post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43499216/pandas-conditional-on-index-column)  but was wondering how to apply the same logic to my problem. I can get specific names by doing : result[result.index == 'Anton'] , but what if i want all names that end with A? result[result.index[-1:] == 'a'] doesn't work either or result[result.index][-1:] == 'a'] for example doesn't work, print((result[result.index][-1:]) == 'a'). Feel like I've tried every variant of the proposed solution.

Comment: You need `result[result.index.get_level_valurs(0).str[-1] == 'a']` if need check first level of multindex and last character.